# How to return a SecureString object from a function

Tags: powershell

How do I return a SecureString object from a function back to a variable?

```
function ReadSecuredFile
{
   [SecureString] $SecuredString;

   $SecuredString = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Testing123' -asplaintext -force;

   return $SecuredString;
}

$a = ReadSecuredFile;
```

**$a** does not get the **$SecuredString** in the statement **return $SecuredString;** in the ReadSecuredFile function. It returns as a System.Object in VS and System.Array in PowerGUI.

Comment: Post a short sample function that contains only the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: OK @Bill_Stewart I created a bear bones example function. If you are able to help that will be great.

Comment: The first line of code in your function is superfluous and actually returns a null object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `[SecureString] $SecuredString;` results in `$null` being returned before the `SecureString` object. Remove that statement

```
function ReadSecuredFile
{
   $SecuredString = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Testing123' -asplaintext -force;

   return $SecuredString;
}
```

Or simpler:

```
function ReadSecuredFile
{
    return ConvertTo-SecureString Testing123 -AsPlainText -Force
}
```

Comment: The `return` statement isn't needed, though it doesn't hurt for it to be there.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen. Thank you very much. Works great. I still don't under why it returns a null instead of the type you declared it as and the last value you set?

In the bigger function I return it with a variable as sometimes I don't care about the value and only return true or false.

Comment: @CostaZachariou It's a cast, not a declaration - powershell doesn't have the concept of variable declarations like C# for example

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen OK makes sense now. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Voila.

```
# Encrypt.
[SecureString] $Local:objPassword = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Password' -AsSecureString;

# Decrypt.
$strPassword = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto( [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR( $objPassword ) );
Write-Host -Object ( 'Decrypted password is "{0}"...' -f $strPassword );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Simon-Catlin but would like to return the [SecureString] object from the function to a [SecureString] object variable.

Comment: Not a problem. :-)